# .NET4.0 SqlConnectionStringBuilder missing ApplicationIntent and MultiSubnetFailover properties

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, connection-string, sqlclient

I have this .Net Framework 4.0 project. I added `System.Data` as a reference.
I am trying to construct a connection string with a `DbConnectionStringBuilder`, instead of directly using a string.

```
        var mssqlcsb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            DataSource = @"(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB",
            InitialCatalog = "test",
            IntegratedSecurity = true,
            ConnectTimeout = 30,
            Encrypt = false,
            TrustServerCertificate = true,
            //ApplicationIntent = ApplicationIntent.ReadWrite,
            //MultiSubnetFailover = false
        };
```

**Error** Code: **CS0117**. Description: '`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`' does not contain a definition for '`ApplicationIntent`'.

Looking up metadata for the class, resolving to *C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll*, **confirms there is no such property**.

However, `ApplicationIntent` is a property for `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.100).aspx). Same issue for `MultiSubnetFailover`.

Am I missing something, is MSDN missing something or is System.Data missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are available as a property, but only with .NET 4.5 or better. It wasn't there in .NET 4.0.

You can easily see that. Create a, say, Console Application project in VS.

Paste the following code in the `Main` method:

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder b = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        b.ApplicationIntent = ApplicationIntent.ReadOnly;
```

The go to project settings and change the "Target Framework" setting to any of the following (depending on what you have installed and what VS version yo are using):

- .NET Framework 4 (=> Compile Error)
- .NET Framework 4.5 (compiles)
- .NET Framework 4.5.1 (compiles)
- ...

You can also see that by looking at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205662(v=vs.110).aspx) document:

> The following connection properties were added to SqlClient in .NET Framework 4.5:
>
> - ApplicationIntent

Change your target framework to .NET 4.5 or better, if you can (i.e. all deployments of your app support this). Or, as a workaround, add those properties manually to the generated connection string:

```
 var mssqlcsb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
 ...
 string connectionString = mssqlcsb.ConnectionString + ";ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite";
```

Comment: Obviously the MSDN docs for 4.0 are not accurate. It's the discrepancy that interested me, not string concatenation :)

Answer (score 0):

"ApplicationIntent" is not available in .net framework 4.0, It is available from .Net 4.5 and above.

Switch your application framework version to .Net 4.5.